# in Flex, how to check if a component exists or not

Tags: apache-flex, components, exists

In flex, How can I check if a component exists?

Comment: You might want to provide more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reference to it,  you can just use

```
var component:MyComponent = new MyComponent();

if (component) {
  // statements
}
```

This seems rather simple and obvious, though. If you want to get more specific, please rephrase the question.